# how to post a status in a group using Facebook graph explorer?

Tags: javascript, c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
Https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/238155829716205
```

I want to post a status in open group what will be the query using facebook graph api thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group/feed#publish

The call is the following

```
POST /v2.3/{group-id}/feed
```

with the appropriate fields included.

Comment: "error": {
    "message": "(#100) A post to a group must have at least a message, tags, or attachment", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
i am adding name and values in graph explorer

Comment: can you tell me posting a status using c sharp please

Comment: why c#? wasn´t the question about how to post with the api explorer?

Comment: anyway, the message is pretty clear, add at least a message to the post. just open the link from tobis answer, everything you need to know is in there.

Comment: i also need c sharp code to post in a status in a group kindly share any link with me

Comment: you just need to use google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440283/facebook-c-sharp-sdk-sample-to-post-to-group-wall

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78089/discussion-between-nouman-arshad-and-luschn).

Comment: please take a look at the official facebook docs and the link i posted. it should be no big deal if you know c#.

Comment: Is there any way doing that with the new API?

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.api(
    "/{group-id}/feed",
    "POST",
    {
       "message": "This is a test message"
    },
    function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
);
```